# SpringBoot Web MVC Application Cannot resolve view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have been using Spring Boot ReST APIs for quite some time; I thought of experimenting with web-MVC. However, I have got stuck on the first part itself.

I have uploaded the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/khandhedia/SpringBootWebMVCDemo1)

What I have done so far:

1. Defined `POM.xml` with `spring-boot-starter-web` + `tomcat-embed-jasper` mainly.
2. Defined a `@Controller` with `@GetMapping("/greeting")`, which returns the name of a view - `hello`
3. Defined following properties:

   `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/`

   `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`
4. Created a very basic view `hello.jsp` at `src/main/web/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp`
5. Created a `main` Application to run as `SpringBootApplication`.

Error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Mar 26 22:55:03 IST 2018
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available

Logs:

```
2018-03-26 22:55:02.998 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /greeting HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8

]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.043 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set query string encoding to UTF-8
2018-03-26 22:55:03.054 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /greeting
2018-03-26 22:55:03.054 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2018-03-26 22:55:03.063 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [C:\Users\NirMit\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.3836668232954126555.8080\conf\jaspic-providers.xml]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.064 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2018-03-26 22:55:03.067 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.068  INFO 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.069  INFO 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-26 22:55:03.069 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'multipartResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.069 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@a8d0be]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.070 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.074 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.074 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.077 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolverCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.079 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.082 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolverCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.084 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.084 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.085 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@1c2a3a2]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.086 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.091 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.091 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.093 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.AbstractThemeResolverCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.095 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.097 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolverCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.098 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.101 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.ThemeResolverCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.108 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.109 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.115 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@1855c21]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewControllerHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'faviconHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.116 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'welcomePageHandlerMapping'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.117 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.117 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.117 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.117 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorAttributes'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.117 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'handlerExceptionResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.121 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.124 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.124 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.126 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslatorCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.128 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.130 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.RequestToViewNameTranslatorCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.132 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.133 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.133 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@99d4c6]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.133 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameViewResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.134 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcViewResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.134 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultViewResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.134 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewResolver'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.137 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.141 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.142 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.143 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractFlashMapManagerCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.146 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.153 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManagerCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.156 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.158 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManagerCustomizer)
2018-03-26 22:55:03.160 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2018-03-26 22:55:03.161 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.161 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@3d023d]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.161 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.161  INFO 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 92 ms
2018-03-26 22:55:03.161 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2018-03-26 22:55:03.177 DEBUG 7132 --- [169.254.165.176] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-169.254.165.176: (port 51150) connection closed
2018-03-26 22:55:03.177 DEBUG 7132 --- [169.254.165.176] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-169.254.165.176: close connection
2018-03-26 22:55:03.200 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1cc2c8
2018-03-26 22:55:03.211 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/greeting]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.217 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /greeting
2018-03-26 22:55:03.223 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.khandhedia.sprinboot.mvc.demo1.controller.GreetingController.greetingForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.223 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'greetingController'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.224 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/greeting] is: -1
2018-03-26 22:55:03.285 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2018-03-26 22:55:03.285 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'hello'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.293 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'hello'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.295 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'hello'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.295 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'hello'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.296 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'name' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'hello'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.307 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'hello'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.318 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.318 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp
2018-03-26 22:55:03.340 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.340 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] are [/**]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.342 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] are {}
2018-03-26 22:55:03.343 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1113a37]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-03-26 22:55:03.344 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] is: -1
2018-03-26 22:55:03.344 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-03-26 22:55:03.344 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-03-26 22:55:03.347 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
2018-03-26 22:55:03.347 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-03-26 22:55:03.347 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1cc2c8
2018-03-26 22:55:03.348 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.349 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.350 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-03-26 22:55:03.351 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.351 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.352 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-03-26 22:55:03.354 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2018-03-26 22:55:03.358 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2018-03-26 22:55:03.383 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2018-03-26 22:55:03.383 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.383 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.383 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@1943f03] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.383 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@1943f03] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-26 22:55:03.420 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-03-26 22:55:03.420 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
2018-03-26 22:55:03.439 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@10910ae:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4cbd6d:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51167]], Read from buffer: [0]
2018-03-26 22:55:03.440 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@10910ae:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4cbd6d:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51167]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2018-03-26 22:55:09.322 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@10910ae:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@4cbd6d:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51167]], Read from buffer: [0]
2018-03-26 22:55:09.322 DEBUG 7132 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
```

**EDIT:**

I tried following changes as per the comments; however, it doesn't seem to help yet.

1. Putting `hello.jsp` in `src/main/resources/templates/WEB-INF/views`
2. Putting `hello.jsp` in `src/main/resources/static/WEB-INF/views`
3. Putting `hello.jsp` in `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/views`
4. Putting `hello.jsp` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views`

Please advise.

Comment: src/main/web, the 'web'  folder should have been 'webapp'

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I tried renaming to 'webapp' and also performed a few more P&Cs, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was with the `provided` `scope` of Maven Dependency `tomcat-embed-jasper` which is used to compile the JSPs.

With **default** scope for this maven dependency, it flies!

```
    <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

***Two cents from my analysis!***

**What is the use of this dependency when we already have spring-boot-starter-web?**

The `spring-boot-starter-web` includes the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` includes the `tomcat-embed-core`.

But, `tomcat-embed-core` doesn't include `tomcat-embed-jasper`.

Now, according to [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), if the `tomcat-embed-jasper` is marked as `provided`, it means that it expects the **JDK** or a **container** to provide the dependency at **runtime**. 
This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and ***is not transitive***.
Hence, effectively this dependency is **not available** when JSPs are being compiled.

By marking this dependency scope as `compile`, it is made available in all the classpaths and to all the dependent projects as well.

**Summary:** The `spring-boot-starter-web` has `tomcat` embedded dependency but it doesn't include the `jasper` embedded dependency. One needs to add this dependency with default `compile` scope.

**Where to place the JSPs/View Components in a Spring Boot Project?**

1. Create a `Web` Project using Spring Inializr or IntelliJ Spring Plugins.
2. Add `Web` framework support using IDE. It may create a directory as `src/main/web/WEB-INF`
3. Rename the directory from `web` to `webapp`
4. Create the view components like JSPs at `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/`
5. Define following properties in application.properties

   ```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
   ```

Answer (score 4):

```
src/main/web/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp
```

will not be found by Spring Boot. As a Spring Boot convention you should put your views under resources folder:

```
src/main/resources/templates/...
```

And for your CSS:

```
src/main/resources/static/...
```

And if you are using Spring Boot, then it's a good idea to use the project initializer:
https://start.spring.io/
from there choose what view technology you want, and Spring Boot will add its dependencies for you, so you don't need to add them or configure them yourself(step 3).

Comment: I tried the suggested changes and few more P&Cs, but it didn't fly though.